# Form submit not posting back on ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have a form in ASP.NET with this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext"
runat="server"
CausesValidation="false"
Text="Submit Form" />
```

I do validation on this form with jQuery Validate, like so:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            txtSerialNumber: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            txtSerialNumber: {
                required: "Please enter a serial number."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

There's more, but it's the same for all the fields. I have verified that this validation code works.

I also have some javascript to call the validation code, since it was not working before (for various reasons).

```
jQuery('#btnNext').on("click", function () {
    if (jQuery("#form1").valid()) {
        jQuery(this).prop('disabled', true); // prevent multiple submits
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Edit: When I comment out the line that disables the button, the form gets submitted correctly. So it seems like disabling a submit button before the page posts back causes the page to not post back.

When I click on this button to submit the form, the javascript above gets called, but the page doesn't post back and submit. I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this figured out. Is there an obvious reason that it's not working correctly? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using update panel?

Comment: Where do you handle the click event on the button? It is a server control, thus you need the onclick event "bound" to a server side eventhandler

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer the button does have a click handler on the server side that does a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: @Gaurav no I am not using update panel

Comment: I don't see the event registration on the button. Besides, aren't you overwriting the click registration of the button by attaching the client side event registration (jquery code snippet)?

Comment: ATTENTION: when you disable the button, the postback is ignored by browsers!, css (display: none) is better way to prevent double postback. or show a ajax gif over button, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `OnClientClick` event to the button, which is going to call the validation, instead of adding the `.on("click")` event handler with jquery.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext"
    runat="server"
    CausesValidation="false"
    Text="Submit Form"
    OnClientClick="validate()" />
```

javascript:

```
function validate () {
   if (jQuery("#form1").valid()) {
       jQuery(this).prop('disabled', true); // prevent multiple submits
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Ended up doing this, but I also added UseSubmitBehavior="false" to the button. It's working now. Thank you!